# Variable n as an upper bound of a for loop

Tags: python, iteration

I wanted to calculate the sum of (1+1+1+...+1)^2 with a for loop, but with a variable n as the upper bound so that the sum results in a function f(n) = n^2. With a non-negative integer x as the input, the loop could easily be coded as

```
p==0
def f(x):
    global p
    for i in range(0,x):
        p=p+1
    return p**2
```

I wanted to feed a string n to this sort of loop. Is this doable (with or without modification)? Do I have to do string-converting hijinks a la SymPy?

edit: wow I worded this problem **really** poorly. guess sleep is important after all

Suppose I have a function f(x), where

```
f(1) = 1  
f(2) = f(1+1) = (1+1)^2 = 4  
f(3) = f(1+2*1) = (1+2)^2 = 9
```

Then, f(n) would be

```
f(n) = f(1+(n-1)*1) = (1+(n-1))^2 = n^2
```

If I were to calculate the result with a for loop above (which is a mess due to sleep deprivation), I'd enter f(1), f(2), f(3),... to the for loop above. I'm asking if I can enter n to the for loop above, with or without modification, and get n^2.

(The relation between f(1), f(2),... here isn't the same as the problem I have right now - I'm just wondering whether this idea is possible or not, and if so, how. I wouldn't learn anything if I ask the question directly, would I?)

edit2: An example of input/output with the algorithm above:

(Integer input)

```
f(1) = 1^2
f(2) = 2^2
f(423) = 423^2
```

(Float input)

```
f(0.5) = (0.5)^2
f(1.5) = (1.5)^2
f(234.23) = (234.23)^2
```

(String input - without assigning integer/float values to these strings first)

```
f(a) = a^2
f(df) = (df)^2
f(the_speed_of_an_unladen_swallow) = (the_speed_of_an_unladen_swallow)^2
```

What I'm aiming for is a modification for the loop above so that I can do this, for f(a) where f is the function above:

```
def g(a):
    return f(a)
```

or the equivalent thereof.

I'm just going to leave this here since I look less like a sleep-deprived uni student and more like a sleep-deprived retarded uni student right now.

Comment: what would you pass? an example perhaps?

Comment: What kind of string? Can you give an example of such input? NB: why the global `p`? Why the loop over the range, when you are effectively returning `x**2`?

Comment: Added more details about the problem on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like `def('123')`?

If so, cast the string to int before using it in `range`, as such:

```
for i in range(0,int(x)):
```

Comment: is the loop really required p should simply be updated as p+= x assuming x to be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> (String input - without assigning integer/float values to these strings first)
>
> ```
> f(a) = a^2
> f(df) = (df)^2
> f(the_speed_of_an_unladen_swallow) = (the_speed_of_an_unladen_swallow)^2
> ```

So, you have variables (`a`, `df`, `the_speed_of_an_unladen_swallow`), which do not yet contain a (good) value at the time you call `f`. Later, they would have a numerical value, and you'd like to loop that many times in your function.

As variables with a primitive data type are passed by value, you would have to pass the name of the variable instead, to do something similar.

Maybe this is something you are looking for?

```
def f(x):
    def localF():
        return globals()[x]**2  # loop could be here, but this is the essence
    return localF

# n does not have its value yet   
n = None

# call f: it should not produce the result yet, as n is not correctly set yet
g = f('n')

# set n to its intended value
n = 5;

# Call the function we got from f:
print (g());

# output is 25.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I afraid this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a modification of a loop for a function f(x) that doesn't give me the error `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`, that happens when you try to put a string directly into a function, when I try to put f(n). The problem is analytically solvable anyway, so I think I'm just going to make f(x) = (the analytic solution) as a sort-of answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add an example of the call to your function, and the desired return value for it. I have no idea what you mean with *when I try to put f(n)*, nor what you mean with the analytic solution. Can you give a concrete example of input/output?

Comment: Added examples and another (hopefully better) explanation of what I'm aiming for. (When I said 'analytic solution' I meant the f(x) that I found with traditional pen-and-paper approach.)

Comment: You write *String input - without assigning integer/float values to these strings first*. But strings are immutable, so you cannot assign something to a string. I suppose you mean a variable, and that you want to pass the variable reference somehow to the function, so that you can later get the result, once the variable has a meaningful value. I rewrote my answer. Maybe this is what you are after?